# apache camel <simple trim="true" is not working

Tags: apache-camel

I'm reading a simple content from a file, say "80631". i validate it against a regex("^\d+$") to check it's just digits. But the validation fails. When i inspect the content read from the file it's something like "80631       ". I tried to trim the whitespace with , but it didn't work. Do we have any other way to trim the whitespace?

```
<camel:setProperty propertyName="messageId">
  <simple trim="true">${body}</simple>
</camel:setProperty>
```

Comment: ${body.trim()} suggested by Claus Ibsen worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should likely show the code to get better help. But `<simple trim="true"> ... </simple>` is trimming the output of the expression.

Its not for trimming message body.

You need to use message transformation beforehand to trim the message body. Or write a regular expression that ignore leading/ending whitespace.

Comment: Thanks, Ibsen. this is my code <camel:setProperty propertyName="messageId">
    <simple trim="true">${body}</simple>
   </camel:setProperty>
When I retrieve the property's value, it still has whitespace.

Comment: Its trimming the whitespace in `<simple>` eg if you break it in multiple lines. You need to do `${body.trim()}` if the body is a String type, or `${bodyAs(String).trim()}` if not.